# How to connect to SQL server from php (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server-2008, ubuntu-16.04

On a Linux/Ubuntu box, I'm trying to connect to an external `SQL Server` database, but I only get errors. I know that the hostname, db name and credentials are correct, and I can't change them.

```
$odbc="odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$database;";
$db = new PDO($odbc, $user, $password);
```

This just gives me `could not find driver`. I have tried every tutorial I could find, and installed tons of packages, and restarted nginx over and over again. I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install drivers for php: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Then update `config/database.php` to use the sqlserv connection and driver:

```php
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),

'connections' => [

    'sqlsrv' => [
       'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
       'host'     => env('DB_HOST',     'localhost'),
       'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'default_database'),
       'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'default_username'),
       'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
       'prefix' => '',
      ],

    //[...]
],
```

After you've done that, you can use `php artisan tinker` to confirm the driver is available:

```
>>> DB::availableDrivers()
=> [
     0 => "mysql",
     2 => "sqlite",
   ]
```

and test your connection:

```
>>> DB::connection()
=> Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection {#161}
```

(Mine doesn't show sqlserv because I don't use that driver)

Comment: Well no. It's Windows thing, and this is a Ubuntu server.

Comment: this should work, if you setup SQL Server on your local Ubuntu

Comment: The original url had links to linux drivers as well, but I've updated it with a new one specific to installing for Ubuntu. Either way you need to install a pdo driver in php in order to be able to connect to SQL Server

Comment: @TravisBritz I have tried that too. But then I just get this `Name too long for LOGINREC field (severity 2) (SQL: SELECT * FROM User)`. It's because the DB name is 49 chars long, and I can't change that.

Comment: That sounds like it connected and you have a new error, which sounds like progress to me

Comment: Haha, a little bit. But it's a dead end, I guess. It must be possible to connect from Ubuntu. It doesn't have to be thru php.

Comment: Finally succeeded to get a connection using [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)